# ctrl-space centos in docker isn't working?

Tags: emacs, docker, keymapping, ctrl

I'm running in a container a Centos *(docker exec -i -t centos bash)* and I have realised that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> isn't working. In fact, I need it for emacs (set-mark-command). So do you know why I have this behaviour?

Thank for your help

Comment: sorry to be pedantic, but `docker exec` connects inside a running container, `docker run` starts a container

Comment: Please add more detail

Comment: user2915097 : Yeah I just wanted to say wich terminal I'm using.
Abrar Jahin : Can you give me wich detail you want? All I can say so you could reproduce this in your environnement, is that when I try to use a shortcut which the combination of control and space, it doesn't work. I realised  that it was due to inability of the terminal to recognise of this combination (it recognize only the space from the combination). 
* I'm running Docker Quickstart Terminal (powershell) on Windows

Comment: I'd say this is a powershell or quickstart terminal issue. Check the docs to see what config options exist for the terminal and see if there is an option which affect the passing through of commands. I don't use windows, but does the C-space binding have a windows binding which might be stealing your keys before it gets to the docker centos instance?